# How to insert at beginning of line not containing character using gvim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to insert the characters (not including the quotes) "* " in all lines in a text file that do not start with the character *.

The following gvim pattern 'almost' works

```
%s/^[^*]/*/gc
```

The problem is that if the line is

```
Bla bla bla
```

then it becomes

```
* la bla bla
```

i.e., First character is over written by the substitution.

I would like to be able to confirm each insertion, because there are some lines in the file where I do not want the "* " to be inserted.

I have looked for this pattern but can't really find any answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Because the pattern matches the first (non-`*`) character, but isn't referenced in the replacement, it gets lost. You can either re-include it (via the special `&` symbol, or `\0` (cp. `:help s/\&`):

```
%s/^[^*]/* &/gc
```

Or you change the pattern to exclude the character from actually matching, via `\ze` (so the match actually immediately ends at the beginning of the line, but it still asserts that there's a non-`*` following):

```
%s/^\ze[^*]/* /gc
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.